# 'Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts.' error

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, connection-string

I have a Xamarin app where you connect to a database. There are no errors in the error list but when I run the code, I get this error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. I use Xamarin.MySql.Data.

I use the same connection string in a windows forms app and it works totally fine. I wrote it yesterday, it is not an old build.

Here is my code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;");
await conn.OpenAsync();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = '" + username.Text + "' AND PASSWORD = '" + password.Text + "'", conn);
    
cmd.Connection = conn;
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(rdr.HasRows)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Successfully Logged In", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Username/Password", ToastLength.Short).Show();
 }
```

Comment: Since it is a Xamarin app, you probably need security permission to access the network.

Comment: @StephenCleary I am very new to Xamarin, I usually work on desktop apps. I followed a tutorial on YouTube that shows how to connect to a MySql database with Xamarin. The system is same. I just modified the bottom part which has no errors on the error list.

Comment: @StephenCleary I dıd a bit of research and find this piece of code on Microsoft documentations. 

`if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Internet) == (int)Permission.Granted)`

and it seems like we have permission to use the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing Xamarin.MySql.Data with MySqlConnector.
It seems Xamarin.Mysql.Data is outdated or something.